# what is the logic in pushing among Views?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to iOS, I have a question about the view.
Lets say I have ViewOne, ViewTwo, ViewThree, ViewFour.
I push the scene accordingly: ViewOne -> ViewTwo -> ViewThree -> ViewFour.
How can I programmatically jump back to ViewTwo dirrectly?
What is the logic for this? Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Way :

```
NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Second Way :

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) 
{

        //Do not forget to import ViewTwo.h
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[ViewTwo class]])
        { 

            [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                                  animated:YES];
            break;
        }
}
```

If you want to pop to first viewController use following:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAniamted:YES];
```

To get more details about NavigationController read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes much sense to me. However, will there be still back button on the navigation after I pop back to ViewTwo?

Comment: Yes. Untill you are on first screen of your navigation stack(ViewOne), back button will be there.

Comment: Thanks Gadhiya, the first way seems easier and faster? the second way needs to go through a loop so does it take more effort to go to 1 screen?

Comment: Second one is useful when you dont know the index of your view.